# unable to run Dataflow pipeline Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error: Unable to open file: gs://

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I found a demo online and I am trying to replicate it. However whenever I run

```
 python pipeline.py --streaming --runner DataflowRunner \
  --project <PROJECT> \
  --temp_location gs://tweeps-stream/temp \
  --staging_location gs://tweeps-stream/staging \
  --region us-west1 \
  --job_name tweeps
```

I get the following error

```
apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error:
Unable to open file: gs://tweeps-stream/staging/tweep.1697803634.304288/pipeline.pb.
```

I am using the GCP cloud console and I gave myself admin for dataflow, bigquery and gcs.

Here is the code I am trying to run

```
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from sys import argv
import apache_beam as beam
import argparse

PROJECT_ID = 'gcp-project'
SUBSCRIPTION = 'projects/' + PROJECT_ID + '/subscriptions/tweeps'
SCHEMA = 'created_at:TIMESTAMP,tweep_id:STRING,text:STRING,user:STRING,flagged:BOOLEAN'

def parse_pubsub(data):
    # use the json library to convert the datafrom pubsub to a python dictionary object
    # makes it much easier to manipulate and Apache Beam also supports python dictionaries directly to BigQuery.
    import json
    return json.loads(data)


def fix_timestamp(data):
    import datetime
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(data['created_at'], "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
    data['created_at'] = d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return data


def check_tweep(data):
    BAD_WORDS = ['attack', 'drug', 'gun']
    data['flagged'] = False
    for word in BAD_WORDS:
        if word in data['text']:
            data['flagged'] = True
    return data


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    known_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions())

    (p | 'ReadData' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=SUBSCRIPTION).with_output_types(bytes)
       | 'Decode' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
       | 'PubSubToJSON' >> beam.Map(parse_pubsub)
       | 'FixTimestamp' >> beam.Map(fix_timestamp)
       | 'CheckTweep' >> beam.Map(check_tweep)
       | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
           '{0}:tweeper.tweeps'.format(PROJECT_ID),
           schema=SCHEMA,
           write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))
    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()
```

My question is:

I do not understand why I am getting this error when I have the correct privileges and running the python app works

```
python pipeline.py --streaming
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a permission issue. Have you checked that the requested file exists in the specified GCS bucket? If so, does the dataflow service accounts have permission to read from this GCS bucket?

Comment: @CaptainNabla the bucket doesn't have any files, just the directory is there. Even using this demo command gives a similar error. https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/create-pipeline-python#run-the-pipeline-on-the-dataflow-service... It might be permissions but I gave myself, owner, viewer and admin on BQ, DataFlow, and Storage.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think `staging_location` is only used if you deploy a dataflow template. What happens if you simply skip this parameter?

Answer (score 1):

By default GCP uses the compute engine service account. I had to create a service account and also a subnet.

```
python pipeline.py --streaming --runner DataflowRunner --project 
{PROJECT_ID} --temp_location gs://{PROJECT_ID}/temp --staging_location 
gs://{PROJECT_ID}/staging --region us-east1 --service_account_email 
dataflow@{PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com -- subnetwork=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/regions/us-east1/subnetworks/subnet
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#permissions. Dataflow uses two service accounts to manage security and permissions.

Comment: I have the correct permissions. By default GCP was using the compute engine account. I had to create a service account to get it to work. Now really what I wanted but it works